# A 'scale-last' content block that keeps uneven spacing ratio

Tags: html, css

I want to have a content block that is **unevenly** centered inside the stage. When scaling down the browser window, the content block should keep its size and use up its surrounding space first.

The space should **keep its ratio** while scaling down:

```
┌───────┬──────────────────────┬───┐
│       │Lorem ipsum dolor sit │   │
│       │amet, consetetur      │   │
│       │sadipscing elitr, sed │   │
│       │diam nonumy eirmod    │   │
│       │tempor invidunt ut    │   │
│       │labore et dolore magna│   │
│       │aliquyam erat, sed    │   │
│       │diam voluptua.        │   │
└───────┴──────────────────────┴───┘
```

*original width.*

```
┌──┬──────────────────────┬┐
│  │Lorem ipsum dolor sit ││
│  │amet, consetetur      ││
│  │sadipscing elitr, sed ││
│  │diam nonumy eirmod    ││
│  │tempor invidunt ut    ││
│  │labore et dolore magna││
│  │aliquyam erat, sed    ││
│  │diam voluptua.        ││<- - -|
└──┴──────────────────────┴┘
```

*scaled down a little. still space left.*

```
┌───────────────┐
│Lorem ipsum    │
│dolor sit amet,│
│consetetur     │
│sadipscing     │
│elitr, sed diam│
│nonumy eirmod  │
│tempor invidunt│
│ut labore et   │
│dolore magna   │
│aliquyam erat, │
│sed diam       │
│voluptua.      │<- - - - - - - - -|
└───────────────┘
```

*scaled down even more. now content gets squished.*

I came up with a solution that uses `calc()` and `@media` queries:
http://embed.plnkr.co/mSucZO7pw9wo9K7sZxy6/
*(Resize the preview window to see the desired behavior)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body, p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      @media (max-width: 300px) {
        .container {
          margin-left: 0;
          margin-right: 0;
        }
      }
      @media (min-width: 301px) {
        .container {
          margin-left: calc((100% - 300px) * 0.6666);
          margin-right: calc((100% - 300px) * 0.3333);
        }
      }
      .wrapper {
        background: #eee;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
      }
      .content {
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 500px;
        background: #ddd;
      }
      .content p {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding: 10px 18px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there some other **pure CSS/HTML** solution that doesn't need `calc()`? My concern is browser compatibility...

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I added the code to the question.

Comment: No problem, anyway, I think my answer(s) gives you what you need,

Comment: Your solution is nice and clear with the pseudo-elements. From what i can see on http://caniuse.com, it also has better browser support. Still, it wouldn't work on IE 8 and below, though.

Comment: If you **really** need to support IE8 then no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of one way and it involves a couple of empty divs and flexbox.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/aZZeaX)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
   margin: 1em auto;
   border:1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
   
}
 
 .content {
   flex: 0 1 300px;
   background: #ddd;
   margin: auto;
 }
 
 .content p {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px;
 }

.left {
  flex:2;
}

.right {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**Updated**

Then again, perhaps a couple of pseudo-elemnts would work as well.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GqqVzq)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  flex: 0 1 300px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: auto;
}
.content p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 2;
}
.container::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```